# C++ Static Function/Namespace issue

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I am having issues with some code. In the `CrossingSensor::loop()` function, there is a line with: `sonar.ping_timer(readSensor);`.

I can call that fine, but in that function I can't access the status variable. What am I missing?

Error: error: 'status' was not declared in this scope status = on;

```
/*
  Name
*/
#ifndef CrossingSensor_h
#define CrossingSensor_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class CrossingSensor
{
  enum Status {off, on};

  public:
    CrossingSensor();
    void init();
    void loop();
    void start();
    void stop();
    Status status;
  private:
    unsigned long _startMillis;
};

#endif
```

```
/*
  NLE
*/

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "CrossingSensor.h"
#include <NewPing.h>

NewPing sonar(2,3,6);//trigger, echo, max distance
unsigned int pingSpeed = 500;// 50ms would be 20 times a second
unsigned long pingTimer;// Holds the next ping time


CrossingSensor::CrossingSensor()
{
  Serial.println("CrossingSensor: Init");
  //init();
}

void CrossingSensor::init()
{
  Serial.println("CrossingSensor: Init/Attach/Reset");
  pingTimer = millis();
}

void readSensor()
{
  if (sonar.check_timer())
  {
    int cm = sonar.ping_result / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM;

    if(cm > 0 && cm < 10)
    {
      //status = on;
    }
    else
    {
      //status = off;
    }
  }
}

void CrossingSensor::loop()
{
  if (millis() >= pingTimer)
  {
    pingTimer += pingSpeed;
    sonar.ping_timer(readSensor);
  }
}

void CrossingSensor::start()
{
  if(status == off)
  {
    Serial.println("CrossingSensor: Turning Sensor On");
    status = on;
  }
}

void CrossingSensor::stop()
{
  if(status == on)
  {
    Serial.println("CrossingSensor: Turning Sensor Off");
    status = off;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you declare `status` in one of the headers? it is not a part of `NewPing.h` as far as I can find in any documentation

Comment: @Hawkeye5450 thanks for response! I added the header to the original post for clarification. Appreciate the help.

Comment: "sensor" is a member of class "CrossingSensor".  You can't access a "sensor" field without having  "CrossingSendor" object.  It looks like maybe you meant for "readSensor()" to be a member function of CrossingSensor?  If so, everything would work fine.

Comment: Thanks @paulsm4 - do you meaning changing void readSensor() to void CrossingSensor::readSensor() ? When I tried that before I saw error: invalid use of non-static member function 'void CrossingSensor::readSensor()' sonar.ping_timer(readSensor); Thanks for help so far.

Answer (score 2):

You never declared the function `readSensor()` as a part of `CrossingSensor`. Since it isn't a member function, it has no access to `status`.

All you should have to do is declare the function as a member of `CrossingSensor` or pass it a `CrossingSensor` object.

You would also need to change the .cpp file to reflect that change. The declaration for each would look like the following:

```cpp
    class CrossingSensor
    {
        enum Status {off, on};

        public:
        CrossingSensor();
        void init();
        void readSensor();
        void loop();
        void start();
        void stop();
        Status status;
        private:
        unsigned long _startMillis;
    };

    #endif
```

This is your method declaration:

```cpp
    void CrossingSensor::readSensor()
    {
        // your code here
    }
```

This makes `readSensor` a part of `CrossingSensor` as well as the other way around.

Comment: THANK you all so far. When I add void readSensor(); to the header file under public: I still get: error: 'status' was not declared in this scope status = on; Thoughts? Thanks guys.

Comment: @user597454 Can you update the files to reflect this change?

Answer (score 1):

The `readSensor()` function isn't part of `CrossingSensor` so it can't see `CrossingSensor`'s `status`.

Make it part of `Crossingsensor` by declaring it there in your header file, and then define it as `void CrossingSensor::readSensor()`, in your code, and not as `void readSensor()`.

Also, I don't know what `sonar.ping_timer()` takes as an argument, but I doubt it is `readSensor`. You will have to find another way of passing `status` to `sonar.ping_timer()`, if that is what you intended to do.

Comment: Thanks @ocrduo, the docs say: sonar.ping_timer(function);     - Send a ping and call function to test if ping is complete. So it takes a function as its param.

Comment: Isn't the function it calls supposed to return something? readSensor doesn't return anything, it is void. Should be in the documentation of NewPing. Also, it won't automatically find that function without your saying what object it is in; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682721/calling-member-functions-within-main-c Don't forget to vote and accept an answer, so the question doesn't stay open.